# MemSQL: change basedir

Tags: singlestore

Somehow I cannot get the base directory to change in MemSQL.

By default MemSQL's base directory is in /var, which on my system does not have enough space. I'd like to move that to an NFS directory as follows:

```
memsql-ops memsql-update-config --all --key basedir --value /nfs/storage/
```

I also tried it with the `--set-global` option. After that I ran

```
memsql-ops memsql-restart --all
```

However, when I then go into MemSQL's command line and issue `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%dir%'; I see that the base directory is still the same. I've also tried to adjust just the`datadir` variable but I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a symlink to a /var/lib/memsql that points to a larger disk. You can follow this set of steps

```
memsql-ops memsql-stop --all
memsql-ops agent-ssh --multi
```

Then you can use a multi-shell to create a directory on each node on your nfs drive, create a symlink to that directory in /var/lib/memsql and move the content from /var/lib/memsql1 to /var/lib/memsql

Comment: I had considered a symlink but I then don't understand why there is an option to change the `basedir` when it makes no difference and you have to do it yourself anyway...

Comment: Another option is to just put the data dir somewhere else: memsql-ops memsql-update-config --key=datadir --value=/tmp/data

Comment: That's what I did and it had no impact. It still saved everything in the /var directories.